# how to draw route from start point to destination point with intermediate points on Open Source Routing Machine?

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-routing-machine

I have four points like this:

```
  Lat            Log

43.532284     -6.060434 

43.533880     -6.065279

43.534269     -6.067436

43.533484     -6.071405
```

If I put these points in Open Source Routing Machine I obtain this map:

[image]

I would like to obtain the map, but with a number in each point intermediate like this:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you have to implement this in your Leaflet code (or whatever map library you are using).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the idea is to do it online with an interactive map.

Comment: @adamista You'd still need some kind of map library for your online interactive map. Draw the labels at the right point (+ offset) using javascript to match your styling needs.

Comment: @adamista That's what Leaflet (or Openlayers) is for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642481/how-to-draw-a-path-between-two-nodes-using-leaflet). I'm not sure if the Polyline will hold to the road like you have shown or it will be 'as the crow flies'.

Comment: Link-only answers are likely to be deleted. Please expand your answer to summarize the SO content in your Answer.